# This version of CLI is only compatible with Angular versions 15

Tags: angular-cli

I have Angular as below:

[image]

When I serve my project it gives me an error as below:

[image]

I have already tried to upgrade to 12 -> 13 -> 14 -> 15
But after going through all this, it still does not work, and gives me errors all over the project.

Could anyone guide me on how to run this project?

Comment: I guess you have to downgrade your angular cli to a version compatible with the angular project version.  here is  11.0

Comment: I even tried that, I downgraded (uninstalled and installed back in) but it is still giving me that same red message, as if it were not downgraded. I then checked via "ng version", and the version was modified to 11. I do not know :(